# C++ portable NaN for win32/Unix

Tags: c++, winapi, unix, gcc

In gcc library, there is a NaN defined in math library to be used for cases like initialize an undefined double variable. However, this NaN is not defined in win32 math lib, I was wondering if there's any way to make this portable? Basically, I just wanted to give a default value to "double" type variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ guarantees that `0.0/0.0` is `NaN`, so this is the easiest way to express it.

Remember that `NaN != NaN`, so `(0.0/0.0) == (0.0/0.0)` is actually false. To test for NaN-ness, if you don't have a library `is_nan` somewhere, just check for `x != x` for some candidate `double x`.

Answer (score 5):

When writing portable C++ code, try using the NaN defined in the standard library `<limits>`. For example for the type `double` you might want to use `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`.